# Turn "Just []" into "Nothing"

Tags: haskell, monads

The following line

```
filterM (\x -> Just (x > 0)) [2, 1, 0, -1]
```

outputs

```
Just [2,1]
```

and the line

```
filterM (\x -> Just (x > 0)) []
```

shows

```
Just []
```

But I would like it to output **Nothing**. What can be done to possibly introduce some change that would work for all monad functions working with lists? So should I use something else instead of filterM or I can do some inheritance from Maybe monad?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason to have three values (`Nothing`, `Just True` and `Just False`) when testing the elements? What's the difference between `Nothing` and `Just False` here?

Comment: Why not simply `if null xs then Nothing else Just (filter (>0) xs)`? I'm not sure how the monad is helping here...

Comment: @PeterWortmann, the question is more about controlling polymorphism here. filterM accepts any monad, Maybe doesn't care about particular type. I would like to fine tune in case of Maybe List

Comment: @Maksee: can you give an example for what you'd like to accomplish with another monad other than Maybe. That might help figuring out what is the generalization that you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand why you want this.  `filterM` for `Maybe` models `filter` with error state. `filterM` on empty list *must* return `pure []` because no error will occur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define:

```
flatten :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe [a]
flatten Nothing   = Nothing
flatten (Just []) = Nothing
flatten x         = x
```

Then

```
flatten $ filterM (\x -> Just (x > 0)) []
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`mfilter`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v%3amfilter) to convert your `Just []` to nothing based on a predicate:

```
 mfilter (not . null) . filterM (Just . (>0)) $ []
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you mean in terms of working for all monad functions working with lists. There is no way to modify the list monad so that this will happen automatically with any monad function, as this would require effectively changing the bind of some other unknown monad. Likewise, changing all of the monad functions would be a bit time consuming.

My suggestion is to use composability. What we want is to fail in the outer monad m if the inner monad, list, is failing. This should be fairly easy, although I'm not sure what to call it, so I will use `failing`.

```
failing :: MonadPlus m => m [a] -> m [a]
failing = (=<<) $ \l -> case l of
    [] -> mzero
    _  -> return l
```

Then `failing $ filterM (\x -> Just (x > 0)) []` should do what you want.

I'm not sure why you're involving Maybe at all in this case though (as your filter conditions both only use Just), but I'm assuming you have some other reason for doing this, or some other condition that sometimes fails.